# Create Excel Xml Mapping from Powershell

Tags: powershell, excel, powershell-2.0, vba

From Powershell, I would like to access an excel file, convert one sheet as Table and link this table to XML using a mapping. I know how to do it in excel and it's working but I want to do it from Powershell.

```
$app = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$wb = $app.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFilePath)
$ListObject = $app.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlListObjectSourceType]::xlSrcRange, $app.ActiveCell.CurrentRegion, $null ,[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess]::xlYes)
$ListObject.Name = "TableData"
```

Above open Excel, convert the sheet into Table. Next is to load the mapping:

```
$map = $wb. XmlMaps.Add("D:\mymap.xsd", "Activity").Name = "Activity_Map"
```

Now the last step is to link the mapping to Excel (Table) Columns (ex: column 5):

```
$ListObject.ListColumns.Item(5).XPath.SetValue($map, "/Activity/Event/", <?> , <?> )
```

I don't know what to set, these are optional but error is raised if not set.

From MSDN, I found that these parameters are: SelectionNamespace (Variant) & Repeating (Variant)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836812%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Can someone help, please?

Thanks,